# October CMS how to get current locale name?

Tags: localization, translation, octobercms

Could you tell me please how i can get current language name or somthing like this.

I want customize Locale Switcher on web site based on October CMS.

It will be greate to recevie something like

```
...
{{ set var = ****.getLocale();}}
...
then use it for switch($var){}
...
```

Answer (score 7):

In twig you can access the current language with `{{ activeLocale }}`, the full language name with `{{ activeLocaleName }}` and an array with all locales available with `{{ locales }}`.

You could use `{{ dump() }}` to see all variables available on a page. If you try it you will find the locale variables right there as well.

Comment: unfortunately {{ activeLocale }} is empty for me.

Comment: @alexwenzel did you add the translate plugin to the page?

Answer (score 6):

i tried with `activeLocale` and also with `locales` array but one can not stop the loop and thus it was impossible for me to render some content conditionally. this is how i solved it, after reading the logic of plugin that how it is working, I did this in one of my partials.

```
==
use RainLab\Translate\Classes\Translator;
protected $translator;

function onStart()
{
    $this->translator = Translator::instance();
    $this['SelectedLanguage'] = $this->activeLocale = $this->translator->getLocale();
}
==
{% set CurrentLanguage = SelectedLanguage %}
```

now `{{CurrentLanguage}}` will give me code for current language so now using twig i can do some conditional rendering like this

```
{% if CurrentLanguage is same as('en') %}{% endif %}
{% if CurrentLanguage is same as('tr') %}{% endif %}
{% if CurrentLanguage is same as('gr') %}{% endif %}
```

Maybe there could be a another solution. but this one worked like charm.

**Update:**

Although, In case of components or elsewhere one can use session to retrieve the current language this way,

```
Session::get('rainlab.translate.locale')
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you use RainLab.Translate plugin?

Create a partial that uses the localePicker component and then use your custom code:

```
<div>{{ activeLocale }} - {{ activeLocaleName }}</div>
{% for code, name in localePicker.locales %}
    <div>{{ code }} - {{ name }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

And just call that partial from where you want to use it.